# Запись в БД через админ панель в django. Не появляется раздел записи в панели

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Создал в проекте django модели

```
    from django.db import models


class Advertisement(models.Model):
    objects = None
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='', verbose_name='Описание')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    price = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Цена', default=0)
    views_count = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество просмотров', default=0)
    status = models.ForeignKey('AdvertisementStatus', default=None, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='advertisements', verbose_name='Статус')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'advertisements'
        ordering = ['title']


class AdvertisementStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

А в admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *


@admin.register(Advertisement)
class AdvertisementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Не понимаю причину вообще...
А вот тут должна же был появиться раздел на добавление записей, а он не появляется
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ7Pt.png

Comment: Вы в settings.py в разделе `INSTALLED_APPS` добавили свое приложение?

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(Advertisement)
```

Попробуйте зарегистрировать модель таким образом в файле admin.py

Comment: Все также, при таком изменении

Comment: А зачем в модели objects = None?  уберите его. не забудьте сделать миграции

Comment: Убрал, не изменилось ничего. Это я в pycharme случайно нажал, но все также все равно.

Answer (score 0):

AdBlock может блокировать отображение моделей в браузере, попробуй его отключить.